# cannot connect to database using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a question that need all of you to help me. I got stuck with it several days. My problem is related to the connection to database using php. Both Mysqli and Mysql are enabled in phpmyadmin. I can connect to database through Mysqli, but i cannot connect through Mysql.

**Here is code**

**Mysqli**

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sample_db');
define('PORT', '80');
define('SOCKET', '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, PORT, SOCKET) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
?>
```

**Mysql**

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sample_db');
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Error " . mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
?>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Well, what happens? What error messages are you getting? (And have you tried simply using identical credentials?)

Comment: tried DB_SERVER just "localhost"

Comment: @Pekka웃: it doesn't show any errors

Comment: @Dagon: it is not work.

Comment: Well, the code doesn't really *do* anything so no output would be the expected result. Do you do anything more?

Comment: it is the connection to database. i will include it to all pages

Comment: So there's no error. How do you know it's not working then? Did you perform a query after this? Was there any error on that?

Comment: Please paste error message what you got.

Answer (score -1):

which type of error you see???
try to use instead of
 `define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');`
 `define('DB_SERVER', 'ipOfTheHost');`

```
// data db
$username = "username";
$pass = "pwd";
$database = "nameDB";
$host = "ipServer"; //my is 62.149.150.187

// connection
mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Argh... it's impossible to connect to it");
```

Comment: It doesn't show any error. Anyways, i have tried with ip, but it doesn't allow to connect to mysql server through ip.

Comment: which provider are u using?

Comment: i'm using cp-vps.rentalserver.jp

Comment: ask directly to them. because is very strange